# Playframework selenium autotest debugging

Tags: selenium, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am developing a play 1 application and testing it with the selenium. In several cases, play auto-test fails when normal testing within a browser (play test) succeeds. This can be due to different behaviour of js/ajax, or development mistakes on my side.

Is there a way to get some more feedback regarding what's going on in the headless browser? For example, assertTitle does give some feedback, as in the test-results HTML the title found is displayed.

Are there ways to get a the whole response at a given point, or any other usable feedback to debug the application and the test cases?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could give some more details about what all things are failing in your tests, give some code examples which u are writing.

Even i had faced lot of issues in running selenium tests in play auto-test, u can refer this link for our issues[Play Auto-tests issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/1fnGj4Lwm5I)

The best way to debug the selenium tests is to use echo and see what are the results it is returning.